# Dado truncado no MySQL

Tags: mysql

Uma tabela do banco de dados tem 5 colunas.

```
1ª id autoincremento [INT[11] NOT NULL]
2ª código do produto [varchar(15) NULL]
3ª nome do produto [varchar[80] NULL]
4ª custo do produto [double[10,2] NULL]
5ª imposto do produto [double[10,2] NULL]
```

[image: Estrutura da tabela]

[image: Índices]

Executando o SQL abaixo:

```
INSERT INTO 
    `produtos` 
    ( 
    `produto_cod`, 
    `produto_nome`, 
    `produto_custo`, 
    `produto_imposto` 
    ) 
    VALUES 
    ( 
    '03202374756', 
    'Produto teste XYZv2', 
    '100.50', 
    '' 
    );
```

O campo "imposto do produto" não é obrigatório (mas também recebe valores de impostos se o usuário preencher o campo relacionado no formulário de cadastro), e pode-se passar o valor em branco, mas o SQL retorna um erro mesmo o campo sendo um valor `NULL`.

> Data truncated for column 'prod_imposto_ipi'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

O erro ocorre, pois mesmo o campo `produto_imposto` aceitando nulo, está recebendo um valor, um valor de uma string vazia: `''`.

Para corrigir essa situação, você pode optar por enviar o valor `null` para o campo `produto_imposto`:

```
INSERT INTO 
    `produtos` 
    ( 
    `produto_cod`, 
    `produto_nome`, 
    `produto_custo`, 
    `produto_imposto` 
    ) 
    VALUES 
    ( 
    '03202374756', 
    'Produto teste XYZv2', 
    '100.50', 
    null
    );
```

Ou remover esse campo do insert, já que ele aceita nulo e você não pretende gravar nada:

```
 INSERT INTO 
    `produtos` 
    ( 
    `produto_cod`, 
    `produto_nome`, 
    `produto_custo`
    ) 
    VALUES 
    ( 
    '03202374756', 
    'Produto teste XYZv2', 
    '100.50'
    );
```

> Criei um exemplo online: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/c0b5c95/1

Comment: Oi, ele não é obrigatório, mas o campo pode sim receber um valor.